# C# form wont fill whole screen

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to make a Windows overlay in C# Windows Forms, but it wont fill the second screen on my setup. I used a command to find all screen resolutions:

Form 1:

```
    Rectangle a;
    Rectangle b;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Hide();
        pictureBox2.Hide();
        Positions();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Screen S in AllScreens)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                a = S.Bounds;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                b = S.Bounds;
            }
        }
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        Work();
        IDK(b);
    }
    void Work()
    {
        Height = a.Height;
        Width = a.Width;
    }
    void MsgBox(string a)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(a);
    }
    void IDK(Rectangle b)
    {
        int showOnMonitor = 1;
        Screen[] sc;
        sc = AllScreens;
        Form2 f = new Form2(b)
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            Left = sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Left,
            Top = sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Top,
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        };
        f.Show();
    }
    void Positions()
    {
        label1.Location = new Point(
        Width / 2 - label1.Width / 2,
        Height / 2 - label1.Height - 40);
        label1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        button1.Location = new Point(
        Width / 2 - button1.Width / 2,
        Height / 2 - button1.Height + 40);
        button1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        linkLabel1.Location = new Point(
        Width / 2 - linkLabel1.Width / 2,
        Height / 2 - linkLabel1.Height + 500);
        linkLabel1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGUI();
        MsgBox(Width.ToString());
        MsgBox(Height.ToString());
    }
    void LoadGUI()
    {
        label1.Hide();
        button1.Hide();
        linkLabel1.Hide();
        pictureBox1.Show();
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        pictureBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        pictureBox2.Show();
        pictureBox2.Location = new Point(20, 188);
        pictureBox2.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
    }
    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Form 2:

```
Rectangle a;
    public Form2(Rectangle b)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        a = b;
        Work();
    }
    void Work()
    {
        Height = a.Height;
        Width = a.Width;
    }
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

The issue is that Form 2 wont fill the whole 2nd screen.
I have no idea why the screen isn't filled completely, the code worked a day ago, but it broke after a windows update (I don't know if this is the issue.).  For all I know this will never work... any help will be appreciated. -Alex

Image Proof:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWdSw.png)
(Bottom Right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to replicate this.  I checked the screen WorkingArea compared to the Bounds:

Screen[0]

> Screen \.\DISPLAY1;
>
> Bounds: {X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1080};
>
> Working Area: {X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1040}

Screen[1]

> Screen \.\DISPLAY2;
>
> Bounds: {X=-1920,Y=-74,Width=1920,Height=1080};
>
> Working Area: {X=-1920,Y=-74,Width=1920,Height=1080}

I thought it might be something to do with the Y-74, but that didn't explain the width.

Ultimately, after a bit of playing, I managed to get it to display as you intended, and I simplified it a bit as well.

The actual fix is instead of setting the form size, I used the `form.SetBounds()`, passing it the screen bounds.  I wrapped it up in a simple function, where you pass it the form and the screen:

```
public static class SetScreen
{
    public static void setFormLocation(Form form, Screen screen)
    {
        Rectangle bounds = screen.Bounds;
        form.SetBounds(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
    }
}
```

I then called it like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.Hide();
    pictureBox2.Hide();
    Positions();
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    SetScreen.setFormLocation(this, Screen.PrimaryScreen);

    Form2 f = new Form2();
    f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    SetScreen.setFormLocation(f, Screen.AllScreens[1]);
    f.Show();
 }
```

Comment: and my visual studio is saying that SetScreen doesn't exist

Comment: I've edited my answer so that you can replace your Form1 initialisation code with mine.  re the SetScreen, I created a separate static Class called "setScreen".  Edited that aobve as well - just make sure it's in the same NameSpace.

Comment: I forgot to comment I just removed setscreen from the code and placed setFormLocation into Form1.cs